# Warnings after renaming of an Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, renaming

I recently changed the name of an iOS app of mine, or more exactly the name of an Xcode project. I am using Xcode 8.2.1.

The old name was OldAppName and the new one is MyApp.

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRnVjtNLLLk as a basic guidance.
The result is not bad, because I successfully changed the name of the project.
And the app is building and running with a new name.

But I get some annoying warning like the following:

```
    file:...MyApp/OldAppName/AppDelegate.swift: warning: Missing file:
    ../MyApp/OldAppName/AppDelegate.swift is missing from working copy
```

If I search for OldAppName under Xcode I don't find anything.

But if I run the following command in the terminal (in my project folder):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l OldAppName \{\} \;
```

I can see that OldAppName is still present in some files.

Is there something I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did adding your file to source control (git commit) solved your problem?

Comment: I did a few things following the post mentioned, but since it didn't work right away it is not clear to see what exactly solved my problem. It seems like the suggestion of removing the file(s) named UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate was the main thing.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed, the  problem has come back. It seems like I need to get rid of the version control for good in order to see the error messages disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Open 'build phases' > 'copy bundle sources' and try to find your file name

Comment: Since I do not see "Copy Bundle Sources". I suppose you mean "Copy Bundle Resources" ?

Comment: Anyway I don't see anything concerning my old app name there.